# Fit AR(1) to i.i.d data

Tags: autoregressive, iid

Suppose I have a stationary time-series $X_t$ . My prior is that the data is i.i.d. .

So if I run the following regression: $X_{t+1}=\gamma_0 + \gamma_1 X_t + \epsilon_{t+1}$, I should get $\gamma_1$ statistically equal to zero, right?

Thanks.

Edit: By statistically different I mean a 2-tailed t-test at 95% confidence level.

Comment: What do you mean by 'statistically equal to zero'?

Comment: You should have $\epsilon_{t+1}$ instead of $\epsilon_t$. And yes, the OLS estimate of $\gamma_1$ will converge to zero. Thus with a large enough sample you can be almost sure that $\gamma_1$ will not be statistically significantly different from zero.

Comment: Yes you are right, I have corrected the $\epsilon$ term. I did simulate data from a N(0,1) and then run the regression above, and I got a statistically different from zero coefficient... (30.000 simulations).

Comment: Please clarify 'statistically different'.  Do you mean that you performed a significance test that rejected the null hypothesis that $\gamma_1=0$? If so, edit this information to the question.

Comment: you'll always get some rejections of a true null in any hypothesis test when run several times!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can show things like consistency (like @RichardHardy mentioned) because (taking $\gamma_0=0$ just to avoid some matrix algebra/manipulations)
$$\hat\gamma_1=\frac{1/T\sum_tX_tX_{t-1}}{1/T\sum_tX_{t-1}^2}$$
which will converge, via a law of large numbers, to
$$
\frac{\gamma_1}{\gamma_0}
$$
where $\gamma_j$ is the $j$th autocovariance of the process, $\gamma_j=E(X_tX_{t-j})$ (again assuming mean zero for simplicity). Now, iid-ness says that ("independence") that $\gamma_j=0$ for $j>0$.

So, 
$$\hat\gamma_1\to_p0$$
In fact, $\hat\gamma_1$ is even unbiased here: As the true $\gamma_1=0$, we have $X_t=\epsilon_t$, so that 
$$
E(\hat\gamma_1|X_{t-1})=E\left(\frac{\sum_t\epsilon_tX_{t-1}}{\sum_tX_{t-1}^2}\Biggl|X_{t-1}\right)=0
$$

Answer (score 1):

To supplement the already good answer by @ChristophHanck, here is R code of a simulation. It shows that with a large enough sample ($T=1000$) you would normally find the coefficient to be significant at $\alpha$ level in $\alpha \cdot N$ cases out of $N$ trials.

```
alpha=0.05 # the chosen significance level
N=10^4 # the number of replications
T=10^3 # the sample size
sig=rep(NA,N) # vector where p-values of the regression coefficient will be saved
for(i in 1:N){
 set.seed(i)
 x=rnorm(T)
 xlag=head(x,-1)
 y=x[-1]
 sig[i]=summary(lm(y~xlag))$coef[2,4]
}
print(length(sig[sig<alpha])) # prints the number of p-values below alpha
print(length(sig[sig<alpha])/N) # prints the number of p-values below alpha divided by the number of trials, N
# It should be approximately equal to alpha, and indeed is 0.0518
```

I am not trying to prove anything here, just to show that the statement in the comment

> I got a statistically different from zero coefficient... (30.000 simulations)

was likely a matter of chance (or due to some mistake).